# Get the NSString between 2 CGPoint values

Tags: iphone

my problem is when i have opened one book in UIWebView. when we tap on UiWebView then get  the CGpoint value , suppose i have 2 CGPoint value. then how to get the String between 2 CGPoint values.

Thanks

Comment: One book as in a PDF or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to draw the string between the CGPoints?  If so, either `drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:` or any of the `drawInRect:` methods from the [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) should do the trick

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's possible, though I feel it should be.  Off hand, I suspect you'd probably want to look into [Text, Web and Editing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html), specifically the "Tasks of a UITextInput Object" subsection as well as the [UITextInput Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)